# What bad things could happen if we don't use sudoedit?

Tags: security, sudo, sudoedit

We know it's safer* to use sudoedit, but what bad things can happen if we have the following in sudoers?

```
Cmnd_Alias FOO = /bin/ed, /usr/bin/ed, /usr/bin/vi
foouser LOCALHOST = NOPASSWD: NOEXEC: FOO
```

Can the "foouser" escape to root prompt? - of course **besides** that he could now edit the /etc/shadow file to put a custom pwd hash to the root user to become root in about 3 seconds..

**Maybe some magic using LD_PRELOAD with ed? How exactly?**

*=sudo ed would run as root. but sudoedit would run as the given user, the edited file will be copied before/after editing it.

Comment: Assuming you provide a strict whitelist of files foouser is allowed to edit?

Comment: no whitelist of files, there is a trick with LD_PRELOAD

Answer (score 8):

> Can the "foouser" escape to root prompt?

Presumably foouser can now open any system binary and "edit" it into something else completely, leaving whatever kind of security hole foouser can dream up.  This has particular potential if you do it to a setuid binary, such as `passwd`, because it means a non-root user could use it do privileged things it was not intended to do.

> besides that he could now edit the /etc/shadow file to put a custom pwd hash

Or just delete the hash, in which case you don't need any password to log in as root.

Comment: If I get it right, the well-known rule of thumb is still never to allow an interactive tool to run as root if it can run a shell, right?

Comment: I guess that depends on whether NOEXEC works.  It seems [it does have a caveat](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html#x50726576656e74696e67207368656c6c2065736361706573) -- namely, it only works with dynamically linked executables (most things are) on systems that support it.  So if you are worried, make sure you check that and do whatever test to see whether, e.g., vi can spawn a subshell.  But no matter what, I think anything with editing/writing capability is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is an incredible amount of files that one can modify to *"install a backdoor"* on the system (editing `/etc/group` is the easiest, but there are lots of more stealthy way to achieve it). It is also possible to disable this `noexec` protection by editing `/etc/sudoers` file! **I wouldn't rely on `NOEXEC` to make "sudo $editor" secure. it is not secure.** DO use sudoedit instead (very carefully because lots of files can be used to gain root privileges !)

Futhermore, sudo's noexec wrapper is tracking a (slowly) moving target (see [sudo_noexec.c history](http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/log/tip/src/sudo_noexec.c) and [The difference between fork(), vfork(), exec() and clone()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856255/1260896)). So the `sudo_noexec` wrapper might not protect you on some Unix variant and it may not restrict new system calls (assuming that your editor use those new API).

To answer specifically you question about `LD_PRELOAD`, the sudo configuration file enables `env_reset` by default to *cause commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment*. So I doubt it could be exploited.

P.S. I have posted a similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200411/16640 !

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't 'what could happen' as much as what *couldn't* happen. I mean, `vi` is quite a powerful tool, and using it as a privileged user gives many potential avenues of attack and exploit.

And that's why you shouldn't do it - because you're playing 'block the mousehole' in a big old house.

Anything interactive is 'risky'. Avenues of attack:

- Shell escapes - NOEXEC helps here.
- Editing system config files - there's a bunch of 'obvious' culprits, like `/etc/passwd` etc. but there's also places where you could, for example, insert a CGI script into an apache instance and privilege escalate that route. Or modify a script called by `root`s crontab. (This is particularly entertaining if they have it NFS mounted!)
- editing system scripts (like the contents of `/etc/rc`).
- Symlink traversal attacks - create a symlink to `/etc/passwd` and then edit *that* to bypass any sort of file whitelisting.

You might as well just give `NOPASSWD: ALL` because all you're really relying on is that your users aren't going to do something dumb as root.

Add on the additional point - lots of people have favourite editors. I've used `ed` when I had to, and mostly use `vim` these days. But not everyone likes them. One of the big advantages of `sudoedit` is that it lets you use whatever.